# Keep recieving TypeError when construction Pony ORM db.Entity object

Tags: python, database, postgresql, ponyorm

I'm trying to insert data into a postgresql database using Pony ORM but when I try to construct an object using a db.Entity class I keep receiving `TypeError: Unknown attribute 'name'`

The class in question looks as followed:

```
class Diet(db.Entity):
    name: Required(str)
    category: Set('Category')
```

This is where the class get created:

```
    for d in data.category.diet:
        print(d)
        diets.append(
            Diet(
                name=d["name"]
            )
        )
```

I'm using Pony ORM version 0.7.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon has to be an equals sign